# Should answers to community wiki automatically become community wiki too?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I just learned from experience that answers to community wiki (CW) questions automatically become CW as well. I wonder if this is a good idea. While some answers easily accept additions, lists are typical, other answers are too specific and should best be left untouched. What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

Part of the reason that Community Wiki isn't able to be applied to questions by normal users is that for the most part, questions also do not readily accept community additions. They are, after all, tailored to the needs of the question asker.

In those rare scenarios where you need the community to build the question (such as Super User's "general virus case" question), then in the same vein it helps to have the community build the answers together. It encourages the question as a whole to be a cooperative effort of not just individuals, but everyone who can. If people should think that users don't need the cooperation, then the question (as with most questions) probably didn't need to be Community Wiki in the first place.